# Setup a git repository to be pushed to

Tags: git

I am honestly not sure how else to phrase the question but here is a better explanation.

We have a Git server at work with all our projects. Now obviously I have pulled these repositories onto my desktop machine at work. However, I can pull the repositories from my desktop machine at work to my home PC via a VPN connection.

When I finish working on something at home, I would like to push to my Desktop machine at work and not directly to the main server yet. How do I setup my work desktop machine so that I can push to it from home.

Currently when I try push to my work machine from home I get the following error:

> git push remoteName branchName 
>   fatal: 'remotePath' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: It would be helpful to know the URL you used for the remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure *remotePath* points to an existing Git repository. Use `git init` to create one.

```
workpc$ mkdir ~/git
workpc$ git init --bare ~/git/myproject.git

homepc$ git remote add workpc username@workpc.example.net:git/myproject.git
homepc$ git push workpc master
```

Notes:

- Do not push directly into a checked-out branch.

  - Most people push into a separate, 'bare' repository (as in the example), and do all editing on clones of it. (Yes, even if on the same machine.)
  - Or you can push into a separate branch with `git push workpc master:fromhome`, then at work `git merge fromhome`.
- It is customary to append "`.git`" to bare repository names, like I did in the example above, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: You've pointed out something I have not done before, usually I just specify 'git init', I have never specified whether it should be --bare and I have never actually named a repository! Going to give that a go! Thanks!

Comment: @FailBoy: The differences are *very* minor: `init` gives you a working-tree and a `.git` subdirectory with Git data, and `init --bare` puts all Git data directly into the repository, without a working-tree. The latter is intended for "remotes", which you push to, pull from, but never edit directly. Similarly, giving a repository name to `init` does *nothing more* than create a new directory by that name, just like `mkdir` would.